# Difference in performance of .last() and :last

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Assuming, that it doesn't matter which one I use for certain functions, does it make any performance-wise difference whether I use

```
$('div:last');
```

or

```
$('div').last();
```

Thanks!

Comment: test it with http://jsperf.com

Comment: http://jsperf.com/jquery-last-selector-vs-last-method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

last() is noticeably faster than :last on big DOM sets, because :last has a lot of added complexity as it can return multiple elements. As a general rule of thumb you probably want to stick with last()

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastItem;  
var divArray = $('div');
if (divArray.length > 0) {
 lastItem = divArray[divArray.length-1];
}
```

Should perform best as it does not use jQuery to iterate through the array to get the last item.